# Django mail error SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed even after setting all the correct details (including DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, smtplib

I am facing various problems (errors) while trying to send mail through django.
I have checked other stackoverflow questions but none helped me
Django version - 4.2
Django email specific settings-

```py
EMAIL_HOST = "county.herosite.pro"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "noreply@bulltrek.com"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASWORD = "myPassword"
```

Commands ran in django shell

```
In [1]: from django.core.mail import send_mail

In [2]: sender_email = "noreply@bulltrek.com"

In [3]: send_mail("Hola","Gola",sender_email,[sender_email])
```

Error I got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMTPServerDisconnected                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 send_mail("Hola","Gola",sender_email,[sender_email])

File ~/snadeepAlgoTradingPlatform/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py:87, in send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, auth_user, auth_password, connection, html_message)
     84 if html_message:
     85     mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
---> 87 return mail.send()

File ~/snadeepAlgoTradingPlatform/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py:298, in EmailMessage.send(self, fail_silently)
    294 if not self.recipients():
    295     # Don't bother creating the network connection if there's nobody to
    296     # send to.
    297     return 0
--> 298 return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File ~/snadeepAlgoTradingPlatform/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py:127, in EmailBackend.send_messages(self, email_messages)
    125     return 0
    126 with self._lock:
--> 127     new_conn_created = self.open()
    128     if not self.connection or new_conn_created is None:
    129         # We failed silently on open().
    130         # Trying to send would be pointless.
    131         return 0

File ~/snadeepAlgoTradingPlatform/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py:85, in EmailBackend.open(self)
     83     connection_params["context"] = self.ssl_context
     84 try:
---> 85     self.connection = self.connection_class(
     86         self.host, self.port, **connection_params
     87     )
     89     # TLS/SSL are mutually exclusive, so only attempt TLS over
     90     # non-secure connections.
     91     if not self.use_ssl and self.use_tls:

File /usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py:255, in SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    252 self._auth_challenge_count = 0
    254 if host:
--> 255     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    256     if code != 220:
    257         self.close()

File /usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py:343, in SMTP.connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    341 self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    342 self.file = None
--> 343 (code, msg) = self.getreply()
    344 if self.debuglevel > 0:
    345     self._print_debug('connect:', repr(msg))

File /usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py:405, in SMTP.getreply(self)
    403 if not line:
    404     self.close()
--> 405     raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
    406 if self.debuglevel > 0:
    407     self._print_debug('reply:', repr(line))

SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I already tried to use SSL instead of TLS, Use different port (though the configuration mentioned only 1), tried different host domain.

Also surprisingly I am able to connect to the mail server and send mail from windows mail!!

Though using the SSL mode I got this error
`SMTPSenderRefused: (550, b'Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)', 'noreply@bulltrek.com')`

I am expecting that this issue is related to django only as in normal smtplib is capable of sending the mail.